# Limit of function $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

I have this function, and I want to take the limit of it. On the open interval (0,1), the limit is 1, but on the closed interval, when you fix $x$ to be equal to 1, then the limit turns into $\frac{1}{2}$. Does that mean there is no limit on the closed interval?

Also, I'm trying to show that the function converges uniformly for $0 < a < 1$, on the closed interval [0, a]. I'm having trouble with how $a$ is not on the interval, but the closed interval is unif. convergent. I understand the need for the "sup-criterion" but I'm struggling to find the supremum that goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$.

Then I need to show that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on [0,1]. My guess is that using the supremum above, the inclusion of 1 makes the limit non-zero and thus the function won't converge uniformly. Might be able to use counter-example too, rather unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **any** $\;a\in [0,1)\;$ , we have that

$$\frac1{1+a^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1{1+0}=1$$

For $\;a=1\;$ the limit is, as you correctly stated, $\;\frac12\;$

Thus, the convergence *cannot* be uniform on $\;[0,1]\;$ since, as all the functions $\;f_n\;$ are continuous, then *also* the uniform limit function would be continuous, and it isn't....

Comment: Okay, so then if $a \in (0, 1)$, is it reasonable to show that the function is uniformly convergent on $[0, a]$ because all $a$ converge to the limit function (which I suppose means it's continuous) or is that not rigorous? Also, if $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$, does this mean that it's peace wise? or simply doesn't exist?

Comment: Indeed: for such $\;0\le a<1\;$, the limit function is $\;g(x)=1\;$ and the convergence is uniform. And over all, yes: the convergence is pointwise.